# Pythonic way to get both diagonals passing through a matrix entry (i,j)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, diagonal

What is the Pythonic way to get a list of diagonal elements in a matrix passing through entry `(i,j)`?

For e.g., given a matrix like:

```
[1  2  3   4  5]
[6  7  8   9 10]
[11 12 13 14 15]
[16 17 18 19 20]
[21 22 23 24 25]
```

and an entry, say, `(1,3)` (representing element `9`) how can I get the elements in the diagonals passing through `9` in a Pythonic way?  Basically, `[3,9,15]` and `[5,9,13,17,21]` both.

Comment: For 9, do you want 3, 9, 15?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Sorry, I have updated the question.  I meant both the diagonals.

Comment: Are you storing the matrix as a list of lists?

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela Do you have numpy?

Comment: @dsaxton, yes I am.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, yes, I do.

Comment: Retitled *"**both** diagonals... **matrix entry***" Also we conventionally refer to matrix entries as (i,j) not (x,y), because they're not points, i.j are integer indices.

Comment: In general if you want to do any serious matrix work, use numpy. Not base Python or storing the matrix as a list-of-lists. So the 'Pythonic' way is use numpy.

Comment: "(1,3)" may be better to be "(2,4)" here because you want both diagonals to pass through $9$ instead of $3$. Then this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49452316/21294350) is better

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using [`np.diagonal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html) with a little offset logic.

```
import numpy as np

lst = np.array([[1,  2,  3,   4,  5],
                [6,  7,  8,   9, 10],
                [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
                [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
                [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])


i, j = 1, 3
major = np.diagonal(lst, offset=(j - i))
print(major)
array([ 3,  9, 15])

minor = np.diagonal(np.rot90(lst), offset=-lst.shape[1] + (j + i) + 1)
print(minor)
array([ 5,  9, 13, 17, 21])
```

The indices `i` and `j` are the row and column. By specifying the offset, `numpy` knows from where to begin selecting elements for the diagonal.

For the major diagonal, You want to start collecting from `3` in the first row. So you need to take the current column index and subtract it by the current row index, to figure out the correct column index at the 0<sup>th</sup> row. Similarly for the minor diagonal, where the array is flipped (rotated by 90˚) and the process repeats.

Comment: Thank you.  Could you kindly explain the parameters you have passed to the diagonal method?

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela Explained to the best of my ability.

Comment: For the second case I am guessing : `np.diagonal(np.rot90(lst), offset=-lst.shape[1] + (j + i) + 1)`. Consider : `lst = np.arange(35).reshape(5,7)+1` to get the idea there.

Comment: @Divakar Thank you so much! Yeah, it was incorrect for that particular input.

Comment: You can write `np.diagonal(lst, offset=(j - i))` way more simply as `lst.diagonal(j-i)`.

Answer (score 0):

As another alternative method, with raveling the array and for matrix with shape (`n*n`):

```
array = np.array([[1,  2,  3,   4,  5],
                  [6,  7,  8,   9, 10],
                  [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
                  [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
                  [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])

x, y = 1, 3


a_mod = array.ravel()
size = array.shape[0]

if y >= x:
    diag = a_mod[y-x:(x+size-y)*size:size+1]
else:
    diag = a_mod[(x-y)*size::size+1]

if x-(size-1-y) >= 0:
    reverse_diag = array[:, ::-1].ravel()[(x-(size-1-y))*size::size+1]
else:
    reverse_diag = a_mod[x:x*size+1:size-1]

# diag         --> [ 3  9 15]
# reverse_diag --> [ 5  9 13 17 21]
```

The correctness of the resulted arrays must be checked further. This can be developed to handle matrices with other shapes e.g. (`n*m`).