# Numpy array: get upper diagonal and lower diagonal for a given element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy
square = numpy.reshape(range(0,16),(4,4))
square

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

In the above array, how do I access the primary diagonal and secondary diagonal of any given element? For example 9.

by primary diagonal, I mean - [4,9,14],
by secondary diagonal, I mean - [3,6,9,12]

I can't use numpy.diag() cause it takes the entire array to get the diagonal.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I didnt know what to call the lists I was refering to. That is why I gave an example. @drooze

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base on your description, with `np.where`, `np.diagonal` and `np.fliplr`

```
import numpy as np
x,y=np.where(square==9)

np.diagonal(square, offset=-(x-y))
Out[382]: array([ 4,  9, 14])

x,y=np.where(np.fliplr(square)==9)
np.diagonal(np.fliplr(square), offset=-(x-y))
# base on the op's comment it should be np.diagonal(np.fliplr(square), offset=-(x-y))
Out[396]: array([ 3,  6,  9, 12])
```

Comment: The second part, doesn't work for square == 11. It gives [1,4]. The code should be:  `np.diagonal(np.fliplr(square), offset=-(x-y))`.Thanks anyway. That was super quick and made my day!

Comment: I am struggling to understand how offset works. Documentation pages - http://www.scipy-lectures.org/scipy_sparse/dia_matrix.html and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html, didnt help much. Should I ask a different question for that? Its important to understand to debug my code.

Comment: @SharvariGc check the picture : -)  https://www.google.com/search?q=offset+of+diagonal+matrix+python&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3-djjmoPaAhXISt8KHSHLCe8Q_AUICygC&biw=1920&bih=949#imgrc=QG3OWIKGum633M:

Comment: any particular pic u would like to refer to? The first 40 hits were mostly on slicing/ indices/representations. Nothing on offset. What does it mean?

Comment: @SharvariGc coding language , but the back end mechanism is the same https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html?requestedDomain=true

Answer (score 0):

For the first diagonal, use the fact that both x_coordiante and y_coordinate increase with 1 each step:

```
def first_diagonal(x, y, length_array):
     if x < y:
          return zip(range(x, length_array), range(length_array - x))
     else:
          return zip(range(length_array - y), range(y, length_array))
```

For the secondary diagonal, use the fact that the x_coordinate + y_coordinate = constant.

```
def second_diagonal(x, y, length_array):
     tot = x + y
     return zip(range(tot+1), range(tot, -1, -1))
```

This gives you two lists you can use to access your matrix. 
Of course, if you have a non square matrix these functions will have to be reshaped a bit.

To illustrate how to get the desired output:

```
a = np.reshape(range(0,16),(4,4))
first = first_diagonal(1, 2, len(a))
second = second_diagonal(1,2, len(a))
primary_diagonal = [a[i[0]][i[1]] for i in first]
secondary_diagonal = [a[i[0]][i[1]] for i in second]
print(primary_diagonal)
print(secondary_diagonal)
```

this outputs:

```
[4, 9, 14]
[3, 6, 9, 12]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I cannot use this cause it creates two more functions and first answer is simpler than this one.

Comment: @SharvariGc I agree, it's better :)