# Longest subarray of same number

Tags: python, numpy

If I had a 2D array of shape `(n,n)` and a given point `(x,y)` and valuer `v` I want to find the length longest sub array in all sub arrays that go through that point e.g.:

```
n=3
x=1
y=1
v=2
array = [
    [1,0,2],
    [2,2,0],
    [2,1,2]
]
```

Then the following arrays would be checked:

- [2,2,0] (horizontal) returns 2
- [0,2,1] (vertical) returns 1
- [1,2,2] (left diag) returns 2
- [2,2,2] (right diag) returns 3

Comment: @Ali_Sh It seems OP looks for the longest subarray of `v` values in these sequences

Comment: @Marat correct but the sub array including diagonals

Comment: @EllisThompson Do you want to get number of repetition of `v` in the specified sub arrays (I get it from the example)? True? If so, I put the answer, if not clear the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have (n*n) matrix, you can use `np.diag` to get values on the main diagonal of the matrix. `np.fliplr` can be combined by `np.diag` to get values on the reverse diagonal. For specified column and row, it can be achieved by indexing on NumPy array. Satisfaction of the condition can be checked by `== v`, which will get a Boolean array with `True` for where value is equal to `v`. Summing the Boolean arrays will get number of `True`s. So it shows the number of `v` in that flattened array:

```
array = np.array([[1, 0, 2],
                  [2, 2, 0],
                  [2, 1, 2]])
v = 2
x = 1
y = 1

horz = (array[x, :] == v).sum()                            # --> 2               
vert = (array[:, y] == v).sum()                            # --> 1
diag = (np.diag(array) == v).sum()                         # --> 2
reversed_diag = (np.diag(np.fliplr(array)) == v).sum()     # --> 3
```

It will works on your prepared `(n*n)` arrays where `x` and `y` are the center of the matrix; Diagonals can be specified by [`np.diag`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html) using parameter `k` if we know which diagonals will pass the point. [there is a good example in this regard on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46135971/13394817).
It may be possible to specify the two passing (from the point) diagonals, *diag* and *reverse_diag*, related arrays by the following relations, too, as another alternative method. The correctness of the resulted arrays must be checked further:

```
a_mod = array.ravel()
size = array.shape[0]

if y >= x:
    diag = a_mod[y-x:(x+size-y)*size:size+1]
else:
    diag = a_mod[(x-y)*size::size+1]

if x-(size-1-y) >= 0:
    reverse_diag = array[:, ::-1].ravel()[(x-(size-1-y))*size::size+1]
else:
    reverse_diag = a_mod[x:x*size+1:size-1]

diag = (diag  == v).sum()
reverse_diag = (reverse_diag == v).sum()
```

I think these solutions will be helpful to solve the problem. If any other results needed, it must be clarified by the OP for further works on.

Comment: this counts all occurrences of `v`, not only the longest sequence

Comment: @Marat, What is the expected output?? The question is not clear enough and needs to show the expected result. **But the main part, I think, is as above**. If the last (`reversed_diag `, which is # 3) subarray is the result and all the numbers are in a flat array, the index of the first occurrence of the max can be find by `np.argmax`, for all occurrence of them `np.where` and `np.max` or `==` can be used. For the complete answer the aim must be clarified.

Comment: I agree the question could be stated better, but IMO it is understandable. It only happens so that each of the four sequences has only one subsequence of `v` values, but the question is to "...find the length **longest sub array in all sub arrays**". Another problem with the answer is that it just happens so that x,y=(1,1) is on the diagonal, but it is not generally true. Consider x,y=1,2, on the same matrix, the return should be 1.